# Getting PHP to work with Apache in WAMP (when upgrading)

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I upgraded to the latest version of PHP and Apache in WAMP per these online instructions:

https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,133665

But when I try to switch over to the latest PHP version I get an error message saying it's not compatible with my version of apache, and when I try to switch over to the latest version of apache it gives an error message saying it's not compatible with my version of PHP!

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a option to stop all services (php, apache, mysql) at once. Then switch both services (php and apache) to the desired version.

After that, start the services one after the other in this order:

1. Apache
2. PHP
3. MYSQL

Comment: I tried this. Even when all are stopped, it still won't let me switch the Apache. :(